# Clojure return for a given academic year

Tags: clojure

```
(defn(yearCode [year]
    (if (= year "freshman") 1
        (if (= year "sophomore") 2
            if (= year "junior") 3
               if (= year "senior") 4 0) 
             )
         )
    )
)


(defn -main []
    (println "\n To find your year:") 
    (print "enter your year: ") (flush) 
    (let 
    [ year (read) ]
        (print "\n your year is ") 
        (print (yearCode year))
        (print "\n\n") 
    )
 )
```

I've tried running my code, but I'm getting a syntax error

Syntax error reading source at (year_code.clj:32:1).

EOF while reading, starting at line 12

Am I missing something or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: The main things right away are the function name shouldn't have a `(` before it (your `-main'` is correct), and your last two `if`s need to be wrapped in `()`s. Fix those, then see what it says.

Comment: You have an extra `(` between `defn` and `yearCode`. FYI you can replace your nested `if`s with a `case` expression.

Comment: You should also include line numbers along with your code.  `year_code.clj:32:1` means the problem is on line 32.  `EOF starting on line 12` says that is where you you have unbalanced parentheses (starting location).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some issues with the parentheses in your `yearCode` function. You have an extra `(` between `defn` and `yearCode` and your last two `if` expression need brackets around them:

```
(defn yearCode [year]
    (if (= year "freshman") 1
        (if (= year "sophomore") 2
            (if (= year "junior") 3
                (if (= year "senior") 4 0)))))
```

However you will probably find using `case` easier:

```
(defn yearCode [year]
  (case year
    "freshman" 1
    "sophomore" 2
    "junior" 3
    "senior" 4
    0))
```

or a map:

```
(def yearCodes
  {"freshman" 1
   "sophomore" 2
   "junior" 3
   "senior" 4})

(defn yearCode [year]
  (get yearCodes year 0))
```

You should also use `read-line` instead of `read` in your main function. `read` converts the result into a clojure form while `read-lines` returns the string directly.

```
(defn -main []
    (println "\n To find your year:") 
    (print "enter your year: ") (flush) 
    (let 
    [year (read-line)]
      (print "\n your year is ") 
      (print (yearCode year))
      (print "\n\n")))
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm getting the hang of it. However, I think my main function may have some issues. The file is still not compiling :/                                                                     Execution error at clojure.main/main (main.java:40).
No namespace: year_code found

Comment: @hkira1 - What's the error? Your `main` function compiles for me so it sounds like your error is somewhere else. Can you edit your question to include all the code?

Comment: I haven't changed the main function code, the question has all of my codes in it. I'm using Linux terminal to compile my clojure file.. What program are you using to compile the codes?

Comment: I loaded it in a REPL and it works as expected. What command are you using from the command line?

Comment: I'm using clojure -m year_code from terminal <-- year_code.clj is my filename

Comment: @hkira1 - What's the `ns` declaration in your file? You'll need an `(ns year_code)` statement at the top of your file.

Comment: It's compiling! but... I'm not getting the results I want.. it's only returning 0 for whatever string i'm inputting

Comment: @hkira1 - Sorry, I realised you do have a small error in your `-main` function as well, see update.